# Populating a combobox with names of fields in a feature class

Tags: arcobjects, c#, combo-box

I have to dynamically populate a ComboBox in an add-in tool for ArcObjects using C# with the names of the fields containing text data in the feature class.

I know I have to obtain the names from the table but I'm not really sure how to go about this at all.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from your code sample what you're up to.

What you're searching for is the enum [esriFieldType](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000004r000000) which can be tested against each field to determine its type:

```
MyComboBox.items.clear(); // empty first

IFeatureLayer pFtLayer = (IFeatureLayer)gMap.get_Layer(0);
IFeatureClass pFtClass = pFtLayer.FeatureClass;
for (int Cnt = 0; Cnt < pFtClass.Fields.FieldCount; Cnt++)
{
    if (pFtClass.Fields.get_Field(Cnt).Type == esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString)
    {
        MyComboBox.items.add(pFtClass.Fields.get_Field(Cnt).Name);
    }
}
```

Assuming your feature class comes from the first layer and your combobox is called MyComboBox... beware to set your [Combobox.DropDownStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList to avoid users (accidentally) typing values in, this would mean that the value in MyComboBox.Text *must* be one of the items in the list or blank.